# Is it possible to check required input with the HTML required attribute without actually submitting the form?

Tags: html, forms

I have a submit button with an onclick event:

`<input type='submit' name='add-row' onclick='addRow()' value='+'>`

My input text boxes all have the `required` attribute.  I'd like to prevent the `onclick` event if the required fields do not hold data, but it looks like the required fields are only checked on submit.  I do not want to submit though because that causes the page to reload (I'll have another button for submitting all the forms at once later on).

Is there a way to force the check on required fields sooner or do I have to check each field manually in my `onclick` function?

Comment: Is `addrow()` a JavaScript function?

Comment: The OnClick event handler needs to run script code that checks the individual form fields for data, and then returns true only if the data is acceptable, otherwise return false to abort the submission.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought that might be what I would have to do. I would have forgotten to return true/false though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnClick` event handler needs to run script code that checks the individual form fields for data, and then returns `true` only if the data is acceptable, otherwise returns `false` to abort the submission.

**Update**: rather than using an `OnClick` event handler on the submit button, you should instead use an `OnSubmit` event handler on the form itself.  That way, having the validation script return true/false has more meaning.

Comment: In my case I return false either way because I don't want to submit the form yet even if the data is acceptable (and if it isn't, my addRow function returns false sooner, before making other changes to the page).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HTML5  pattern attribute. More info at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

It prevents the form from being submited if a regex pattern is not match by the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

## Aim:

- Use Required Attributes of the input to validate.
- Dont allow the form to submit via get or post method but want to perform some dom manipulations using javascript programmatically.
- The reason i am trying to do all this is because my form is in a modal and on submit, i need to do few validations including that of checking whether a group of checkboxes have been checked or not.

> We can use onsubmit="function()" and action attributes of the form in a different manner as follows:

```
<form onsubmit = "someFunc()" action="javascript:void(0)">
<input .........  required>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

What the above code does is allows you to validate input fields within your form having the **required** attribute when you click **submit.** . Also the form wont get submitted as action is set to javascript:void(0)

Now you can perform the required actions like validations inside the function **sumfunct** .

for eg, i had to check whether a group of checkbox have been checked or not.
So i used the following code .

```
if($('div.checkbox-group.required :checkbox:checked').length > 0){
return true; } else { return false;}
```

Hope This helps!